# Unable to upload a file through protractor?

Tags: typescript, npm, protractor, cucumber

I am practicing on uploading a file through protractor in this particular web application:
https://www.fileconvoy.com/

beacuse, when I get my angular  web application I need to automate the upload functionality.

I am unable to upload the file and its throwing error like below:

VError: a BeforeAll hook errored, process exiting: typeScript\support\hooks.js:14: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 100000 milliseconds

I tried the below suggested options in SO but all in vain:

1).Running the autoit.exe code and whenever that window pop-up it'll directly provide the path.
2).through sendKeys

3).Through the below code:

```
    var ele=element(by.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
    //await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(ele),1500);
    ele.click();
    var path = require('path');
    var fileToUpload = '../file/Capture001.png',
    absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    await ele.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

I am new to protractor so require some help.Can anyone suggest me some working code on how to fix this?
Thank you.

[image: Project folder structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works for me, no need for click event:

```
var ele = element(by.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './../../file/Capture001.png');
await ele.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

P.S. using `xpath` selectors is [NOT recommended](https://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide), consider other selector strategies.

Comment: No, that didn't work.I am getting error like: invalid argument: File not found : D:\protractor-cucumber-typescript-master\typeScript\stepdefinitions\fileCapture001.png.I have created a folder name "file" in the project folder and in that I had placed Capture001.png file is there.Whats wrong over here?

Comment: @AmrishSukumaran Obviously the problem is not in the scenario itself, but in the file path, try `./../file/Capture001.png`

Comment: Yeah, that I understood. I tried the one which you suggested but, that also is not working :( .In my project folder , file(folder)->Capture001.png file.How can i write the file path so that it identifies?

Comment: could you please add a folder structure to your question? I'm interested where `file` folder is, relatively test file folder

Comment: added my project structure

Comment: I see where `Capture001.png` is, but where is a file with the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187233/discussion-between-lunin-roman-and-amrish-sukumaran).